# Выборка через like на ограниченное число записей

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть очень большая таблица в БД MySQL. Можно ли найти записи через оператор like на определенной части таблицы, например вывести все записи из первых 1000 строк с оператором like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

С точки зрения синтаксиса - точно можно, и разными способами. Ниже - один из простых. Во вложененом запросе ограничиваем таблицу до 3 строк и ведем поиск с 'LIKE' на наличие буквы "а" только по ней. Четвертая запись отсекается.
На реальной большой базе не проверял это, конечно. Возможно, имеет смысл ещё по id упорядочить (`ORDER BY id` вставить перед `LIMIT`) во вложенном запросе - зависит от базы.

```
/*Это просто создание тестовой базы и вывод ее*/
CREATE TABLE example(
    column1 VARCHAR(25),
    id INT    
);
INSERT INTO example
    VALUES
    ('a', 1),
    ('b', 2),
    ('a', 3),
    ('a', 4);
SELECT * FROM example;  
/*Непосредственно сам запрос*/
SELECT column1, id
FROM (SELECT *
      FROM example
      LIMIT 3) q
WHERE column1 LIKE '%a'
```

Результат:

```
Affected rows: 0

Affected rows: 4

Query result:
+---------+----+
| column1 | id |
+---------+----+
| a       | 1  |
| b       | 2  |
| a       | 3  |
| a       | 4  |
+---------+----+
Affected rows: 4

Query result:
+---------+----+
| column1 | id |
+---------+----+
| a       | 1  |
| a       | 3  |
+---------+----+
Affected rows: 2
```